# Count number of days with date range in one table and days criteria in another table

Tags: r, data.table

My one table has data with date mentioned in last two columns:

```
dat<- data.frame(a = c(rep("x",3)),
                 date1=c(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-3"), 1)), 
                 date2=c(seq(as.Date("2018-01-08"), as.Date("2018-01-10"), 1)))
```

a       date1       date2

1 x 2018-01-01  2018-01-08

2 x 2018-01-02  2018-01-09

3 x 2018-01-03  2018-01-10

My another table has what kind of day each day is

```
cal <- data.frame(dt = c(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-10"),1)),
                  day = c(rep("workday",5), rep("holiday",1), rep("weekend",4)))
```

How to get number of days in table 1(dat) as anew column such that the it counts only the workday that falls in the range mentioned in column 2 and column 3?

**Example output with 4 columns. The last column is the number of workdays for the date range in previous two columns**

```
  a      date1      date2     countdown
1 x 2018-01-01   2018-01-08           5
2 x 2018-01-02   2018-01-09           4
3 x 2018-01-03   2018-01-10           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` solution

```
library( data.table )
#set data to data.table format
setDT(dat); setDT(cal)
setkey(dat, date1, date2 )
dat[dat, 
    N := { val = cal[ day == "workday" & dt >= i.date1 & dt <= i.date2 ]
           list( nrow( val ) ) }, 
    by = .EACHI ]

#    a      date1      date2 N
# 1: x 2018-01-01 2018-01-08 5
# 2: x 2018-01-02 2018-01-09 4
# 3: x 2018-01-03 2018-01-10 3
```

**update**
data.table::foverlaps() solution

```
library( data.table )
#set data to data.table format
setDT(dat); setDT(cal)
#create dummy date
cal[,dt2 := dt]
#set keys
setkey( dat, date1, date2 )
setkey( cal, dt, dt2 )
#overlap join
ans <- foverlaps( dat, cal )
#summarise
ans[, .( countdown = uniqueN( dt[day == "workday"] ) ), by = .(a, date1, date2)][]
#    a      date1      date2 countdown
# 1: x 2018-01-01 2018-01-08         5
# 2: x 2018-01-02 2018-01-09         4
# 3: x 2018-01-03 2018-01-10         3
```

Comment: but this very slow in a bigger data. Anyway this can be made faster?

Comment: @Deb updates the answer with a `data.table::foverlaps()`-approach... should work pretty fast

Comment: foverlaps doesn't work if there are NA values in the columns. Is there any way around it?

Comment: there are no NA's in your sample data? If there are in your production data, fill them, of filter them out of the joinin proces

Answer (score 1):

A way using `tidyverse` functions :

1. Create a sequence of days between `date1` and `date2`
2. Get the data in long format
3. Left join data the above data with `cal` dataframe
4. Calculate number of workdays for each row.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(),
         dt = purrr::map2(date1, date2, seq, by = '1 day')) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(dt) %>%
  left_join(cal, by = 'dt') %>%
  group_by(row, a, date1, date2) %>%
  summarise(countdown = sum(day == 'workday')) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)

#   a     date1      date2      countdown
#  <chr> <date>     <date>         <int>
#1 x     2018-01-01 2018-01-08         5
#2 x     2018-01-02 2018-01-09         4
#3 x     2018-01-03 2018-01-10         3
```

Comment: any data.table solution?

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
within(
  dat,
  countdown <- sapply(
    1:nrow(dat),
    function(k) sum(cal$day == "workday" & !is.na(cut(cal$dt, c(date1[k], date2[k]))))
  )
)
```

giving

```
  a      date1      date2 countdown
1 x 2018-01-01 2018-01-08         5
2 x 2018-01-02 2018-01-09         4
3 x 2018-01-03 2018-01-10         3
```

Answer (score 0):

additional solution

```
# v1
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(int_date = list(seq(date1, date2, "1 day"))) %>% 
  unnest(int_date) %>% 
  left_join(cal, by = c("int_date" = "dt")) %>% 
  filter(day == "workday") %>% 
  group_by(a, date1, date2) %>% 
  count

# v2
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(int_date = list(seq(date1, date2, "1 day")),
         out = sum(unlist(int_date) %in% cal$dt[cal$day == "workday"])) %>% 
  select(-int_date)

# v3 (using @Ronak Shah hint with a `map` )
df %>% 
  mutate(int_date = map2(date1, date2, seq, "1 day"),
         out = map_dbl(int_date, ~ sum(.x %in% cal$dt[cal$day == "workday"]))) %>% 
  select(-int_date)


# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  a     date1      date2        out
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <int>
1 x     2018-01-01 2018-01-08     5
2 x     2018-01-02 2018-01-09     4
3 x     2018-01-03 2018-01-10     3
```